# The code after crossing the number of lines limit is masked

Tags: bug, design, android-app, code-formatting

I noticed that in the Stack Exchange Android app, when the posted code crosses the normal limit of number of lines to be shown, the rest of the code gets masked with white color rather than hiding the rest of the code or revealing it totally.

> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image: screenshot]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: HUAWEI
- Device Model: PRA-LA1
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (371(C185))

Comment: Please be aware that all development on the app has ceased in 2017 and is unlikely to continue anytime soon, or ever.